# angular.js routing and stateparams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, meanjs

I'm trying to modify standard user module of meanjs. I added a simple route:

```
state('users', {
            url: '/users/:username',
            templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/view-profile.client.view.html'
        });
```

And in my view:

```
data-ng-controller="ViewProfileController" data-ng-init="findUser()"
```

I also injected $stateParams to my controller. So in my `ViewProfileController` - `findUser` function, when I write this:

```
console.log($stateParams.username)
```

I expect to get username parameter. But it returns `undefined`.

When I set the route this way,

```
state('users', {
            url: '/users/:username',
            template: function ($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.username;
            }
        });
```

it returns username. I don't know what is wrong or missing. Any ideas?

edit: this was my full controller code

```
'use strict';

angular.module('users').controller('ViewProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Users', 'Authentication', 
function($scope, $http, $location, Users, Authentication, $stateParams) {
    $scope.user = Authentication.user;


    $scope.findUser = function () {
        console.log($stateParams);
        ...
    };
}
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies don't match up - the list of dependencies need to match the parameters in the controller function in the same order:

```
'use strict'; 
angular.module('users')
.controller('ViewProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Users', 'Authentication', 
  function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Users, Authentication) { 
    $scope.user = Authentication.user; 
    $scope.findUser = function () { 
      console.log($stateParams); 
    }; 
  }
]);
```

Comment: works! i had no idea about that since i'm fairly new to this stuff. it seems very obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

I should use controller instead of template.

Replace into you code the `template:` to the follow snippet:

```
controller: function($stateParams){
    console.log('username: '+$stateParams.username);
}
```

[You can see a complete example of this feature here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gmtcE2?p=preview)

Comment: i need to pass username to the modules/users/views/view-profile.client.view.html and then to the controller using ng-controller. i cant see how this helps

Comment: `'use strict';

angular.module('users').controller('ViewProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Users', 'Authentication',
    function($scope, $http, $location, Users, Authentication, $stateParams) {
        $scope.user = Authentication.user;


        $scope.findUser = function () {
            console.log($stateParams);
        
        };
    }
]);`

Comment: Your dependencies don't match up - $stateParams is the the 3rd param in the dependency list, but the last parameter in your controller function.

Comment: @marcieng I suggest updating the question with your controller code so that the Accepted Answer makes sense ... I had no idea how Brad knew your dependencies were wrong from the question :)